# converting sql query into cakephp format

Tags: sql, cakephp

**Hi**

i need the following sql query into cakephp find() format. the query it self is working fine but i need to change it.

```
$this->Part->query(
    "SELECT `parts`.`id`,`parts`.`part_name` 
     FROM `parts`  
     LEFT JOIN ( 
         SELECT `op` . * 
         FROM `order_parts` AS `op` 
         WHERE `op`.`order_id` =".$this->Session->read('orderid')."
     ) AS `vT` 
     ON ( `parts`.`id` = `vT`.`part_id` )
     WHERE `vT`.`part_id` IS NULL"
);
```

thanks

Comment: Post your *Parts* model. Particularly the relationships.

Comment: parts to order_parts is 1 - many relationship, i just need to get the part_id and part_name from the parts table. also there is another table involved which is order, and the order has a 1 to many relationship to order_parts. so order to order_parts is 1 to many

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but the relationship you should have between parts and orders would not be HABTM which is done through the table orders_parts?

Comment: Post your Parts and Order relationships. Do you have OrderPart model?

Comment: parts and orders has a many to many relationship, and when i broke it down i get the orderparts as the middle table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your relationship are Order HABTM Part and you have a table orders_parts with columns: id, order_id,part_id you should be able to do something like this:

First, get the ids of the parts which are in the order:

```
//each Part has one OrdersPart per order
$this->Part->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('OrdersParts')));
$parts = $this->Part->find('list', array(
  'fields' => array('Part.name'),
  'conditions' => array(
    'OrdersParts.order_id' => $this->Session->read('orderid'),
  ),
  'recursive' => 2
));
```

Now get the parts which are not in the order:

```
$this->Part->find('all', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    "NOT" => array('Part.id' => array_keys($parts))
  ),
));
```

Comment: Hi Xsphere: let say i have orderid=2; my query above is asking the database give me all the parts from the part table which does not exists in the the order_parts table for orderid =2. now your query is getting all the parts that exists in the order_parts table for orderid=2. hope this make sense

Comment: Oops @TimorMangal- I should have read your query more carefully. In that case I would do two queries: first do a find('list'...) as per my first answer to get the ids of the parts which are in the order. Then do another query to get the parts which don't have those ids. I'll amend my answer.